# How to prevent keyboard dismiss when bottomsheet is dismiss using swipe gesture (Interactive dismiss) iOS

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a requirement where we need to keep close active unless bottom sheet is not closed. I have seen similar implementations in iOS maps where search keyboard is opened until the view is fully dismissed.

What I have currently :-
[image]

What I want :- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SmXniFp0ZTF5igMzk6gk3eflCeP1xjn6/view?usp=share_link

This is code which i use to to present iOS native sheet :-

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            isPresented.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            BottomSheetViewRepresentable(content: {
                NavigationView {
                    DemoView()
                }
                .navigationTitle("Hey")
            }, detents: [.large()])
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct DemoView: View {
    var body: some View{
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            ZStack {
                TextField("", text: .constant("Hey"))
            }
            .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.never)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            Color.yellow
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have added **.scrollDismissesKeyboard(.never)** on the ZStack which seems not working.
Try wrapping content in a **List** or **ScrollView**, then set scrollDismissesKeyboard to never.
Examples -

```
var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Name", text: $username)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                TextEditor(text: $bio)
                    .frame(height: 400)
                    .border(.quaternary, width: 1)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.never)
    }
```

List example -

```
struct KeyboardDismissExample: View {
        @State private var text = ""
        
        var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                    TextField(("Item \(i)"), text: .constant(""))
                }
            }
            .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.never)
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. 
This won't work. Reason :-
1. If i wrap my whole content with ScrollView then native swipe to dismiss gesture won't work and my bottomsheet won't be dismissed on swipe as it will have gesture conflict with ScrollView 
2. Even if I use scrollview and have some other padding/view on the top/bottom  `.scrollDismissesKeyboard(.never)` will only work on scrollview and not complete bottomsheet. 

What I want is user can use scroll to dismiss but keyboard should only disappeared once bottomsheet is closed.