# SwiftUI PKCanvasView in a .sheet hides/dismisses tools when dismiss is triggered

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, first-responder, pencilkit

I have a `DrawingView` which is presented inside a `.sheet` in SwiftUI:

```swift
...
.sheet { DrawingView() }
```

```swift
struct DrawingView: View {
    private var canvasView = PKCanvasView()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                MyCanvas(canvasView: canvasView)
            }
...
```

That view hosts my PKCanvasView:

```swift
struct MyCanvas: UIViewRepresentable {
    var canvasView: PKCanvasView
    @Binding var oldImage: UIImage?
    let picker = PKToolPicker()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
        self.canvasView.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .black, width: 15)
        self.canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
        return canvasView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {
        print(#function, uiView.drawing.strokes.count)
        picker.addObserver(canvasView)
        picker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: uiView)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good, but when I start to dismiss the sheet the PKView automatically dismisses the tools. When I then swipe the sheet back up they're gone. I can still paint with the last selected pen, but that's it. I assume it's a first responder issue? That SwiftUI tells the PKCanvasView to remove the responder, and it therefore dismisses the tools, right?
Similar similar to the keyboard being dismissed: ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74656876/how-to-prevent-keyboard-dismiss-when-bottomsheet-is-dismiss-using-swipe-gesture))

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use `canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()` and `canvasView.resignFirstResponder()` manually to handle with it

Comment: Yes, but where do I call it from? `.onDissapear` and `.onAppear` aren't called when the sheet is only partially dismissed and un-dismissed again.